# Package.appxmanifest not showing all 7 Tabs

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I re-targeted my project from wp8 to wp8.1. At first my package.appxmanifest file's build action was not set to Appxmanifest. Also it is only showing 4 tabs

-Application
-capabilities
-Declarations
-Packaging

Tabs that are missing are

-Visual Assets
-content URI's
-Declarations

What should i do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" xmlns:m2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2013/manifest" xmlns:m3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/manifest" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest">
  <Identity Name="37576f76-9ac9-4f78-b2d9-cb51446fb500" Publisher="CN=R" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="e4312153-3f4c-49dd-904d-5fbe8f1d6000" PhonePublisherId="3f72d71c-dd80-408e-affb-aa06372f300a" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>app</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>app</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Prerequisites>
    <OSMinVersion>6.3.1</OSMinVersion>
    <OSMaxVersionTested>6.3.1</OSMaxVersionTested>
  </Prerequisites>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="xe4312153y3f4cy49ddy904dy5fbe8f1d6073x" Executable="AGHost.exe" EntryPoint="MainPage.xaml">
      <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="app" Square150x150Logo="Assets\SquareTile150x150.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Logo.png" Description="app" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646" ToastCapable="true">
        <m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Assets\SquareTile71x71.png">
        </m3:DefaultTile>
        <m3:SplashScreen Image="SplashScreenImage.jpg" />
        <m3:ApplicationView MinWidth="width320" />
        <!--Used in XAML Designer. DO NOT REMOVE-->
      </m3:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>AgHostSvcs.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="AgHost.BackgroundTask" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight-based apps don't have those extra tabs; they are only applicable to non-Silverlight (WinRT) apps. You set things like your Tile icons via the **WMAppManifest.xml** file.

Comment: I am using WNS push notifications service. So I cant change tiles icon from their either